# Directory content sizes integrated into `ls`?

Tags: linux, ls

`ls` lists directory contents. `du` lists directory content size. Is there some way to get a `ls`-like listing but with directories showing content size?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want with just "ls".  Also, a very similar question with much discussion can be found by a quick google:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019116/using-ls-to-list-directories-and-their-total-sizes

Comment: To get a listing that resembles a mix of `ls` and `du` will require a custom script.  It can probably be done in a few lines.  It implies using `ls`, checking if the file is a directory, calculate its size with `du` and properly output your results.  Show us your best effort and we'll help you pinpoint your mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

Put this shell function declaration in your shell initialization scripts:

```
function duls {
    paste <( du -hs -- "$@" | cut -f1 ) <( ls -ld -- "$@" )
}
```

I called it `duls` because it shows the output from both `du` and `ls` (in that order):

```
$ duls
210M    drwxr-xr-x  21 kk  staff  714 Jun 15 09:32 .

$ duls *
 36K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff    35147 Jun  9 16:03 COPYING
8.0K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff     6962 Jun  9 16:03 INSTALL
 28K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff    24816 Jun 10 13:26 Makefile
4.0K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff       75 Jun  9 16:03 Makefile.am
 24K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff    24473 Jun 10 13:26 Makefile.in
4.0K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff     1689 Jun  9 16:03 README
120K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff   121585 Jun 10 13:26 aclocal.m4
684K    drwxr-xr-x   7 kk  staff      238 Jun 10 13:26 autom4te.cache
128K    drwxr-xr-x   8 kk  staff      272 Jun  9 16:03 build
 60K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff    60083 Jun 10 13:26 config.log
 36K    -rwxr-xr-x   1 kk  staff    34716 Jun 10 13:26 config.status
264K    -rwxr-xr-x   1 kk  staff   266637 Jun 10 13:26 configure
8.0K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff     4280 Jun 10 13:25 configure.ac
7.0M    drwxr-xr-x   8 kk  staff      272 Jun 10 13:26 doc
2.3M    drwxr-xr-x  28 kk  staff      952 Jun 10 13:26 examples
6.2M    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff  6505797 Jun 15 09:32 mrbayes-3.2.7-dev.tar.gz
 11M    drwxr-xr-x  42 kk  staff     1428 Jun 10 13:26 src

$ duls doc
7.0M    drwxr-xr-x  8 kk  staff  272 Jun 10 13:26 doc

$ duls [bM]*
 28K    -rw-r--r--  1 kk  staff  24816 Jun 10 13:26 Makefile
4.0K    -rw-r--r--  1 kk  staff     75 Jun  9 16:03 Makefile.am
 24K    -rw-r--r--  1 kk  staff  24473 Jun 10 13:26 Makefile.in
128K    drwxr-xr-x  8 kk  staff    272 Jun  9 16:03 build
```

Explanation:

The `paste` utility creates columns from its input according to the specification that you give it.  Given two input files, it puts them side by side, with a tab as separator.

We give it the output of `du -hs -- "$@" | cut -f1` as the first file (input stream really) and the output of `ls -ld -- "$@"` as the second file.

In the function, `"$@"` will evaluate to the list of all command line arguments, each in double quotes. It will therefore understand globbing characters and path names with spaces etc.

The double minuses (`--`) signals the end of command line options to `du` and `ls`.  Without these, saying `duls -l` would confuse `du` and any option for `du` that `ls` doesn't have would confuse `ls` (and the options that exist in both utilities might not mean the same thing, and it would be a pretty mess).

The `cut` after `du` simply cuts out the first column of the `du -hs` output (the sizes).

I decided to put the `du` output on the left, otherwise I would have had to manage a wobbly right column (due to varying lengths of file names).

The command will not accept command line flags.

This has been tested in both `bash` and in `ksh93`. It will not work with `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l` will show you the sizes of files within a directory. `du -sh *` will show you the size of the directories.

Comment: Yes, I stated that. Now how do you combine the two to get an `ls`-like listing with directories listed showing `du`-like sizes.

Comment: "Is there some way to get a ls-like listing but with directories showing content size?" Yes, `du -sh *`

Comment: `du` does not produce an `ls`-like listing. For example, it does not show flags, owner, group, time stamps, or type.

Comment: Ah, you never specified that you wanted ls in long-list format. `ls` on it's on only shows filenames.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do what you want with some rather complex `sed` calls:-

```
ls -d Directory/*|while l="$(line)";\
   do s=$(du -sb "$l"|sed "s/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/"); ls -ld "$l"|\
      sed "s/^\(d[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *[^ ]*  *[^ ]* \) *[^ ]* /\1\[$s\] /g";\
   done
```

Note:-

1. I have put square brackets round the directory sizes, to distinguish them from the file sizes.
2. The tabulation on the directory entries will be offset, because of the different string lengths of the sizes reported by `du`, but the commands could be refined further to account for this.
3. It would be significantly simpler if there were no blanks or other unprintable characters in the file names.
4. The command works by substituting the directory size returned by `ls -l` with the size returned by `du -s`; because of the complexity of the substitution `du` is called before working out if it is necessary to do so, in order to simplify the scripting.
5. It would be better to use something like `[ "$l" == "${l#d}" ] && echo "$l" || { s=$(du ...); sed ...; }` to check for a directory and only then call `du` and make the substitution.
6. If you don't have a `line` command you can use `while read -r l; do ...`, but this loses leading and trailing blanks, so I use `line` as a matter of course.

I did write a `line` script which uses `read` while preserving all blanks:

```
read -r; r=$?; echo "$REPLY"; return $r 2>/dev/null; exit $r
```

(The complicated return/exit sequence stops the shell from exiting if called called using `.` / `source`.)

Answer (score -1):

If you read the man of [`ls` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html), you'll see there’s a `-h` option, which shows you in human readable type the size of each file inside a directory.

Comment: That still gives only the directory's node size (usually 4K) rather than the size of the directory's content. Additionally, I wanted the directories shown in a listing to show their content sizes rather than the size of the listing itself.

Comment: You can use then du -hs to see how much is the diretory' size.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the question. The question is asking how to integrate `du`-like sizes into an `ls` listing.

Comment: I've read the man of ls and I'm afraid it can't do what you're asking. Use du instead.